# loadNativeCode not registered

Tags: android, android-ndk

I try to get a android app running, which implements part of it's code in native.
It does find the shared library, but when it attempts to run it in the Emulator and it calls `loadNativeCode` I get:

```
AndroidRuntime(1342): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: loadNativeCode
```

As far as I traced the code it seems to miss a call to `register_android_app_NativeActivity` which sets up the `loadNativeCode` mapping. But since this is done in the runtime I have no clue why it does not work.

Comment: probably the native library (some .so in /libs iirc) is missing in the apk

Comment: The one that has the code you use from Java - no idea what exactly that is in your case

Comment: As stated above, it does locate my native library successfully.

Answer (score 0):

```
JNI
loadNativeCode native function MUST format as:

Static way:
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_tapir_android_jniutils_test_MainActivity_emptyf(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
...
}
package name is com.tapir.android.jniutils.test
class name is MainActivity
function name is emptyf

Dynamic way,use RegisterNatives to register your native function in JNI_onLoad function

JNINativeMethod nm;
nm.name = "emptyf";
/* method descriptor assigned to signature field */
nm.signature = "()V";
nm.fnPtr = native_emptyf;
env->RegisterNatives( cls, &nm, 1);

native_emptyf MUST like as 
void native_emptyf(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
...
}

hope can help u
```